# duplicate selection of Check boxes in android listview

Tags: android

Am using check boxes in listview and am able to get the selected values also but my problem is when select the first position checkbox, automatically selecting 7th positioned checkbox. what will be the problem and please suggest me how to resolve this problem.

```
public class TransactionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflator;
    String veh_reg_no;
    String fuel_qty, total_amt;

    public TransactionAdapter(Context context) {
        inflator = getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    
        if (pso_transaction_list.size() != 0)
            return pso_transaction_list.size();
        return 0;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     

        final Viewholder holder;
        if(convertView==null) {
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.pso_transation_layout, parent, false);

            holder=new Viewholder();

            holder.vT_tl_regnumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vT_psotl_regnumber);
            holder.vT_tl_drivername = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vT_psotl_drivername);
            holder.vT_tl_quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vT_psotl_quantity);
            holder.vT_tl_totalCost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vT_psotl_totalCost);
            holder.vT_psotl_payment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vT_psotl_payment);
            holder.vI_psotl_statusimg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vI_psotl_statusimg);
            holder.vI_pha_Next = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vI_pha_Next);
            holder.vI_pha_select = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vI_pha_select);
            holder.vT_psotl_unit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vT_psotl_unit);
            holder.vT_pha_rsr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vT_pha_rsr);
            holder.vL_psotl_nextlayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vL_psotl_nextlayout);
            holder.vL_psotl_checkboxlayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vL_psotl_checkboxlayout);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.vI_pha_select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        }
       
        if (pso_transaction_list.get(position).getPaymentMode().getId() == 1 && pso_transaction_list.get(position).getWFStatus() == 7) {
            String pmt_status = "C/A | RCVD ";
            holder.vT_psotl_payment.setText(pmt_status);
        } else if (pso_transaction_list.get(position).getPaymentMode().getId() == 1) {
            holder.vT_psotl_payment.setText("C/A");
        } else {
            holder.vT_psotl_payment.setText("P/G");
        }

        if (pso_transaction_list.get(position).getFuelStations().getCountry() != null) {
            String[] currency = Getlocationaddress_by_address.currency(pso_transaction_list.get(position).getFuelStations().getCountry(), PsomytransactionlistActivity.this);
            holder.vT_pha_rsr.setText(" " + currency[0] + " ");
            holder.vT_psotl_unit.setText(" " + currency[1]);
        }

     


        holder.vI_pha_select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked{

                if (isChecked) {
                 
                    selected_list_payment.add(pso_transaction_list.get(position).getPaymentMode().getId() + "");
                    selected_list.add(pso_transaction_list.get(position).getId() + "");
                    selecteddetails.add(pso_transaction_list.get(position).getVehicleNo());
                    payment_status.add(pso_transaction_list.get(position).getWFStatus() + "");

                } else {
               
                    selected_list.remove(pso_transaction_list.get(position).getId() + "");
                    selected_list_payment.remove(pso_transaction_list.get(position).getPaymentMode().getId() + "");
                    selecteddetails.remove(pso_transaction_list.get(position).getVehicleNo());
                    payment_status.remove(pso_transaction_list.get(position).getWFStatus() + "");
                }
            }
        });
        

        veh_reg_no = pso_transaction_list.get(position).getVehicleNo();
        holder.vT_tl_regnumber.setText(veh_reg_no);
        holder.vT_tl_drivername.setText(pso_transaction_list.get(position).getDriver().getName());
        fuel_qty = " " + pso_transaction_list.get(position).getQuantity() + "";
        holder.vT_tl_quantity.setText(fuel_qty);
        total_amt = pso_transaction_list.get(position).getTotalPrice() + "";
        holder.vT_tl_totalCost.setText(total_amt);

        holder.vL_psotl_nextlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent trans_intent = new Intent(PsomytransactionlistActivity.this, Psotransactiondetails.class);
                trans_intent.putExtra("trans_details_position", position);
                startActivity(trans_intent);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}


public static class Viewholder{

    public TextView vT_tl_regnumber, vT_tl_drivername, vT_tl_quantity, vT_tl_totalCost, vT_psotl_payment, vT_psotl_unit, vT_pha_rsr;
    public ImageView vI_psotl_statusimg, vI_pha_Next;
    public LinearLayout vL_psotl_nextlayout, vL_psotl_checkboxlayout;
    public CheckBox vI_pha_select;
}
```

Comment: please post your adapter code here

Comment: are you displaying six items at a time?

Comment: this is the issue of recycling view..you need to maintain array of that

Comment: Try to use recyclerview instead of listview

Comment: did you try with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. this worked for me

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final Context context;
    private List<ModelPooja> listData;

    public CustomAdapter(Context mainActivity, List<ModelPooja> listData) {
        context = mainActivity;
        this.listData = listData;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_poojaselection, null);
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojaname);
            holder.checks = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojacheck);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.checks.setFocusable(false);

        if (listData.get(position).isselected) {
            holder.checks.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.checks.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean b) {

                if (checkMaxLimit()) {

                    if (listData.get(position).isselected && b) {
                        holder.checks.setChecked(false);
                        listData.get(position).isselected = false;

                    } else {
                        holder.checks.setChecked(false);
                        listData.get(position).isselected = false;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Max limit reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (b) {
                        listData.get(position).isselected = true;
                    } else {
                        listData.get(position).isselected = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        holder.tv.setText(listData.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_NAME());
        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean checkMaxLimit() {
        int countermax = 0;
        for(ModelPooja item : listData){
            if(item.isselected){
                countermax++;
            }
        }
        return countermax >= 5;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv;
        public CheckBox checks;
    }
}
```

For Recyclerview try this way

http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Add two functions into your "Adapter" class
Note: If you use RecycleView, just add getItemViewType(int position).